# Logstash forwarder conf for multiple server ips

Tags: ssl-certificate, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-forwarder

I was trying to connect my logstash forwarder with multiple Logstash servers but I can't figure out how to have a single certificate for all the servers. I am able to connect to each of them individually and I have different certificates for each of them.

The details in `/etc/logstash-forwarder.conf` are:

```
"servers": ["123.123.123.123:5000","456.456.456.456:5000"]  
"ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
```

Comment: Your config should be fine as long as you have the same cert for the servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a certificate for *.yourdomain as described in [logstash-forwarder docs](https://github.com/elastic/logstash-forwarder#important-tlsssl-certificate-notes).

Your config should be something like this:

`"servers": ["server1.yourdomain:5000", "server2.yourdomain:5000"]`